# Whats wrong with this javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-5

Below code not working in IE. Console shows syntax error. Whats wrong with this?

```
var text = '{"products":[' +
'{"name":"IB-400","mail":"9000@mail.pl"},' +
'{"name":"IB-500","mail":"8000@mail.pl"}]}';
var textObj = JSON.parse(text)
var mail = textObj.products.find(itm => itm.name == c).mail
$( ".komunikat" ).replaceWith( '<div class="komunikat-mail"><h1 style="text-align:center;">Contact</h1><p class="komunikat-paragraph">Lorem ipsum  ' + mail +'. Lorem ipsum.</p></div>' );
```

Comment: Show the syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They syntax error is because you're using an arrow function in a browser that doesn't support them.

Change `itm => itm.name == c` to `function ( itm ) { return itm.name == c }`.

or use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile ES6 to ES5 for you.

Comment: It works in IE but then not working   $( ".komunikat" ).replaceWith( '<div class="komunikat-mail"><h1 style="text-align:center;">Contact</h1><p class="komunikat-paragraph">Lorem ipsum  ' + mail +'. Lorem ipsum.</p></div>' );

Comment: @gainsky I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Code is working in IE but there is a html statement with var mail. In chrome, mozilla etc. works but var mail not working in IE.